# Getting Duplicate emails after filling bootstrap contact form

Tags: php

i am first time asking here, I don't know php coding ,i have one contact form on my webpage ,after filling which i get emails but twice in my inbox, I really don't know what changes should make in scripting here.i have added recptcha code here too by refering videos and docs but in php scripting there getting problem after submitting form

```js
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['tel']) && isset($_POST['loc']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $tel = $_POST['tel'];
 $loc = $_POST['loc'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

 if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "Kindly provide valid Email Address.";
 } else {
  $body = $name . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $tel . "\n" .  $loc . "\n" . $message;

  if (mail('services@brickboys.com.au', 'Service Enquiry', $body, 'From:' . $email)) {
 echo (mail('services@brickboys.com.au', 'Service Enquiry', $body, 'From:' . $email))."Thanks for contacting us.";
  } else {
   echo "<script>alert('Sorry!, there is a problem in sending email. Please call us on +61 452 534 200')</script>";
  }
 }
} else {
 echo 'Message could not be sent.';
}



$curlx = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$post_data = 
[
    'secret' => '6LfRXOEhAAAAAOWyRGugvbPdYOhkztlz1aMcEwKP', //<--- your reCaptcha secret key
    'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
];

curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$resp = json_decode(curl_exec($curlx));

curl_close($curlx);

if ($resp->success) 
{
    echo "<script>alert('Thanks For connecting us..we will get back to you soon..')</script>";
} else 
{
    // failed
    echo "<script>alert('Please verify you are human..')</script>";
    exit;
}

?>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 padding-15">
                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <!-- https://brickboys.com.au/contact.php -->
                        <form action ="https://brickboys.com.au/contact.php"
                        method="post" id="ajax_form" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group colum-row row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group colum-row row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{10}" placeholder="Phone 0452534200" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" id="loc" name="loc" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Location">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha col-sm-6 mt-2" data-sitekey="6LfRXOEhAAAAAJMek8MJn-kTKIzO-AKfg7JIp3zu"></div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button id="submit" class="default-btn" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="form-messages" class="alert" role="alert"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Reason: you have called mail() twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mail('services@brickboys.com.au', 'Service Enquiry', $body, 'From:' . $email)) {
    echo (mail('services@brickboys.com.au', 'Service Enquiry', $body, 'From:' . $email))."Thanks for contacting us.";
}
```

The problem in these lines you're calling `mail()` function within the `if` statement. You just need to echo your message there doesn't need to call the mail function again.

This is how you'll write your if statement.

```
if (mail('services@brickboys.com.au', 'Service Enquiry', $body, 'From:' . $email)) {
    echo "Thanks for contacting us.";
}
```